# How to export compute geometric measures from Meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

I want to use meshlab to compute geometric measures function.

Currently, I call meshlab by c++ and open a project with 10 layer ply format. I want to run the compute geometric measures of meshlab and saved the calculations inside a text file.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Using Commandline (MeshLabServer)

- Write a MeshLab filterscript `filter.mlx` with the following content

  > ```
  > <!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
  > <FilterScript>
  >   <xmlfilter name="Compute Geometric Measures"/>
  > </FilterScript>
  > ```
- Call `meshlabserver` from command line as follows. It will print the output on the console

  > ```
  > meshlabserver -i input.ply -o output.ply -s filter.mlx
  > ```

### Using VCG

- [VCG](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib/) is behind all the mesh manipulation MeshLab provides. It is a header only library you can use in your project to do most of what MeshLab provides.
- For computing geometric measures similar to how MeshLab does it using VCG, refer MeshLab source for that particular [file](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/blob/master/src/meshlabplugins/filter_measure/filter_measure.cpp#L179).

Answer (score 0):

you can also export the properties (or any other outputs from meshlabserver) to a text file using:
meshlabserver -l properties.txt -i input.ply -o output.ply -s filter.mlx